# Laravel: Retrive all relationships from a Many To Many (Polymorphic) Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a classical many-to-many polymorphic relationships.

For example I have two models `Post` and `Video`. The models can be tagged with a model `Tag`. A `Tag` can belong to many `Post`s and/or `Video`s. And a `Post` (`Video`)  can have multiple `Tag`s.

Now I want to receive all connected models (`Post`s  AND `Video`s) for a single tag.

I know I can do `$videos = $tag->videos` but then I only get the videos. I want to do something like `$models = $tag->getAllConnectedModels()` to have an array of all `Post`s  and `Video`s. How can I do this?

---

Here are the definitions of the models

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}

class Video extends Model
{
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
}


class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Post', 'taggable');
    }
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you used many to many or one to many (polymorphic) ?

Comment: Yes, I need many to many.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this method in your tag model,

And use `merge` on collection:

```php
 public function getAllConnectedModels()
 {
    return $this->posts->merge($this->videos);
 }
```

So when when you call `$tag->getAllConnectedModels()`, it will return something like this:

```php
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#33740
     all: [
       App\Post {#2984
         id: 1,
         ...
       },
       App\Video {#8999
         id: 3,
         ...
       },
     ]
```